# How to split a stream to two binaries with retry?

Tags: pipe, signals, tee

I have a binary that produces an audio stream in s16le format. I want to split this stream to two different processes, but I don't want the command to exit and interrupt process 1 if process 2 errors. Basically what I want is:

`$ ./input | tee >(process_1) | process_2`

Except if process 2 exits, I want to restart it. By default if process_2 exits, the whole command will exit when the pipe signal propagates.

I know I can do this in C by explicitly handling the signals and writing my own logic, but wondering if there's a better way with native bash to trap/handle the signals and restart downstream processes without interrupting the command itself.

In this case I'm splitting audio data between a recording and a webstream:

`get_audio | tee >(./recorder) | ffmpeg -i pipe: ...`

The issue here is that if ffmpeg's connection to IceCast is interrupted, the entire command will terminate but I'd like the former process to continue recording uninterrupted.